# Could not resolve non-optional dependency

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IdFactory
{
     Id Create(Guid userId);
}
```

and the Castle Windsor definition is like this:

```
container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration
    .Component.For<Id>().ImplementedBy<Id>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
 var ID = IDFactory.Create(new Guid(userId));
```

The error I get is:

> Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DependencyResolverException: 'Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'Id' (Id). Parameter 'id' type 'System.Guid''

What is the problem here? Do I have to configure `System.Guid` in Castle Windsor?

Comment: It may be appropriate to make two Create methods - one without parameter - where the Id is implicitly created in it like your case and another with the parameter, which is explicitly provided. I suspect this is the case, because otherwise you can ask the question - Why do I have method with explicitly stated parameter which I create implicitly by a factory through the container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter names of factory method and of class constructor being resolved must be the same:

```
public class Id
{
    public Id(Guid userId /*not - Guid id*/)
    {
    }
}
```